# i am using parse.com push notification feature but it works for prelollipop devices see details below thanks

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

push notification working on pre lollipop devices only .

i have entered my details like sender id and api key  of gcm service in setting>push on parse.com website but still my app is not receving pus notification on lollipop any solution for this guys or any proble with my mainifest file or any other thing i need to setup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="package name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="packge_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="packge_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application
        android:name=".app"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme1">
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LogIn"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_log_in">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Signup"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_signup"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme1">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomePage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_page">

        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />


                <category android:name="packge_name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: where it says packge_name in permission did you put your package name?

Comment: yes i have hidden it :)

Answer (score 0):

On android emulator version 23 -- I think there is no problem, Because I have tested on it. After that tried it on version 22 emulator -- And it works there also. I think there is some another problem with version 23 emulator. My max sdk is 22 hence I didn't need it. But can anyone ans why its not working on api 23 emulator (Excepting good explanation). Sorry for spell, I am bad in English but good in programming :)